# how do i keep centered div with max-width from collapsing when using flexbox column?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 3 divs vertically stacked in container. I want middle div to be centered but continue expanding horizontally as much as it can but less than max-width. Just like normal div would with max-width without flexbox involved.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XaQXOW

css

```
.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.b {
  max-width: 500px;
  background-color: cyan;
}
.a, .b, .c {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100px;
}
```

html

```
<div class="cont">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it something like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OjGNLE

Comment: Have you tried `.b {background-color: cyan; max-width: 500px; align-self: center; width: 100%; }`?

Comment: you defined the width, i want width to be auto as in it contracts if parent does, and it expands if it can but also respect max-width and be centered

Comment: try this one 
 > .b {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 190px;
} it;s help full i thing

Comment: i dont want fixed width

Comment: Instead of using max-width, have you tried with `min-width:40%` ? or is `max-width` necessary? Check this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OjGNLE

Comment: if you don't width use { min-width: 60px;} like : https://jsfiddle.net/hs3kb8zd/

Comment: @OvidiuUnguru behavior is different with min-width on smaller viewport, it stay 40% of available space whereas max-width would have it take all of it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set `align-self: center;` to center your div and add `width: 100%`:

```css
.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.b {
  max-width: 500px;
  background-color: cyan;
  align-self: center;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.a, .b, .c {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome! :) Note that `box-sizing: border-box;` fixes issues with width and border.

Comment: A slight variation on this is to set `width: calc(100% - 40px)` for a 20px margin-left and right. This can be useful if you need to enforce a margin and don't want to use padding (+ border-box) for whatever reason. I couldn't find another way to specify margin, have it 'fill' the remaining space and also have a maximum width.

Comment: I still dont understand why setting align-self center would collapse the div?

Answer (score 5):

You may want to use margin-left and margin-right and set them auto

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/MMRahman/51fmqruh/)

HTML

```
<div class="cont">
 <div class="a"></div>
 <div class="b"></div>
 <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.cont {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

.b {
  background-color: cyan; 
  max-width: 500px; 
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%; 
}
.a, .b, .c {
 border: 1px solid #000;
 height: 100px;
}
```